# Показ части кода при выбранном пункте select

Tags: html, select

Есть следующий список:

```
<form action="users.php" method="post" name="dropdownlist">
    <p><select id="workname" size="1">
        <option disabled selected>Выберите интервал</option>
        <option>Неделя</option>
        <option>Месяц</option>
        <option>Неделя</option>
        <option>Выберите даты...</option>
        </select></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Выбрать"></p>
</form>
```

При выборе пункта "Выберите даты" должно появляться следущее:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
    С <input type="date" name="start_date" /> до <input type="date" name="end_date" />
    <input type="submit" value="Показать" size="40" name="godate">
</form>
```

Подскажите как реализовать пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изначально форму скрываете, на onchange выбора даты вешаете обработчик, который показывает или скрывает форму.

```js
$(function(){
  $('#workname').change(function(){
    if ($(this).find('option:selected').data('type') == 'range') {
      $('#hidden-form').removeClass('hidden');
    } else {
      $('#hidden-form').addClass('hidden');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="users.php" method="post" name="dropdownlist">
    <p><select id="workname" size="1">
        <option disabled selected>Выберите интервал</option>
        <option>Неделя</option>
        <option>Месяц</option>
        <option>Неделя</option>
        <option data-type="range">Выберите даты...</option>
        </select></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Выбрать"></p>
</form>

<form name="form1" id="hidden-form" method="post" action="" class="hidden">
    С <input type="date" name="start_date" /> до <input type="date" name="end_date" />
    <input type="submit" value="Показать" size="40" name="godate">
</form></div>
```

Comment: Но я бы не стал делать отдельной формой, лучше просто скрывать / показывать поля ввода.

Comment: Спасибо за быструю помощь, сделал как посоветовали (скрыл поле)